# Perform an action when post is updated/published

Tags: functions, actions

I'd like to run a custom query using some meta data whenever a post is updated or published.

Is there something I can put in functions.php to fire when those events occur?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `save_post` action fires When a post is updated and/or published -- including when a new post is inserted.

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse41912_save_post' );
function wpse41912_save_post()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

If you want your functions to fire only when a post is being edited, you can hook into `edit_post`.

If you want it to fire when a post is moved from draft to publish you can hook into `transition_post_status`.

Comment: save_post is for when it's created or updated. You will want publish_post for when it's actually posted. If you don't do that - then drafts and such will be impacted as well.

Comment: save_post is fired whenever `wp_insert_post` is called.  On everything -- drafts, whatever.  If you want to stop it from being called during auto drafts, you can check `if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return` somewhere in the function hooked into `save_post`.

Comment: +1 for `edit_post` function

Answer (score 5):

[There are several actions you can use](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Post.2C_Page.2C_Attachment.2C_and_Category_Actions_.28Admin.29). For example:

- `save_post`
- `edit_post`
- `publish_post`
- etc.

While lesser-used, there are also [post-status transition hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).

Answer (score 3):

the edit_post hook is probably the best hook... as it fires whenever a post/page is published or updated.  save_post is another viable option... maybe better if you don't need it to fire when comments are updated.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

the save_post page in the codex has an example of a function that fires whenever a post is saved:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an action when any custom post update/save -

```
add_action('save_post','save_post_callback');
function save_post_callback($post_id){
global $post; 
if ($post->post_type != 'MY_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_NAME'){
    return;
}
//if you get here then it's your post type so do your things....
}
```